# Program not reading '?' after separation of strings by '?' as well as '.'

Tags: python, string, list

I have an original text file that is one very long string. I separated this file / string using '?' and full stop '.' in order to be able to go through it sentence by sentence, and I saved these sentences / strings into a list called `sentences_list`.

I'm reading the strings in that list, in order to count the number of '?' symbols but it's not picking up the '?' symbol at all. How can this be?
Here is the code for the function that looks for the '?' :

```
def count_question_symbols(list):
    count = 0
    for item in list:
        if "?" in item:
            count += 1
    print("Questions asked", count, "times")

count_question_symbols(sentences_list)
```

And here is the code where the 'sentences_list' is created:

```
file = open("classic_cars.txt", "r")
sentences_list = []
for line in file:
    sentences_list.extend(re.split(r"[?\.]\s*", line))
```

Comment: Try using `\?` in the regular expression?

Comment: @vanPelt2 I tried: ‘re.split(r"[\?.]\s*", line))‘ like so, and (re.split(r"[\?\.]\s*", line)) but they didn't work. Then I printed item, to check it, and all sentences are stripped of the . and ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separation isn't that necessary:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as f: # Stores all text as a string in a variable
    sentences_list = f.read()

def count_question_symbols(string):
    count = len(string)-len(string.replace('?','')) # Calculate the difference when subtraction original string with partial string
    print("Questions asked", count, "times")

count_question_symbols(sentences_list)
```

Output:

```
Questions asked 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.split` is mostly an over complication of the goal.
In python, files can be converted to strings rather easily.
The `count` method is great when testing if a substring is contained within a string.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        count = f.read().count("?")
        print("Num question marks: " + str(count))
        # or in 3.6+
        print(f"Num question marks: {count}")
```

Note that a happy accident of the function provided is that it works on most sizes of strings. (not just whole lines from files)

Comment: I still don't know why, but your method picked up 1 question symbol. The other answer picked it up 5 times which is the correct number of symbols. What could be making the difference do you think?

Comment: Ah, yeah this solution assume there is only one `?` per line of text.
If you have multiple copies of the question mark on one line then it won't count them.

Comment: updated the code with a better solution to account for multiple occurrences

Comment: Thanks Taylor. That worked! It's really good to know about this method as well so thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: just glad to help